# Generic Addition Function Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I want to make a function which could take two parameters and based on the type of the input it should perform binary operation(E.g. 'int' simple addition , for string it should concatenate etc..) and return the result . I am getting errors like "Binary operator ‘+’ can not be applied to two ’T’ operands" for following method

```
func commonAdd <T>(paramA:T,paramB:T)->T
```

Comment: Let's say I pass to the function 2 `UIButton(s)`, what should be the result?

Comment: There should be some way to define the functionality in case of all the new kind of inputs

Comment: So you want to define a rule for **every** possibile type supported by Swift? I mean **every** type in **every** Apple framework and in **every** third party library? Are you sure?

Comment: What ever is cover under the scope of Concept of Generic

Comment: The problem is that with this signature `func commonAdd <T>(paramA:T,paramB:T)->T` you provide a guarantee that given 2 inputs of the same type you will be able to sum them. But this is not possible because I can define my own type `struct Foo { }` that (of course) will not be managed by your code.

Comment: Yes , So Generic concept in swift will be suitable for what kind of operations and scenarios .

Comment: And you have to remember about the mixed types like a sum between a float and an int.

Comment: @Brduca: please note that since the function uses `T` for both params, the compiler will make sure that they have the same type. So scenarios where and `Int` is added to a `Float` is not allowed at compile time.

Comment: Ya this point is mentioned in apple docs already .

Comment: @Amulya: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach.

### 1) The Addable Protocol

You define an `Addable` protocol.

```
protocol Addable {
    func add(other:Self) -> Self
}
```

### 2) The commonAdd function

Next you define you function this way

```
func commonAdd <T: Addable>(paramA:T,paramB:T) -> T {
    return paramA.add(paramB)
}
```

### 3) Making Int conform to Addable

Next you pick a Type and made it conform to `Addable`

```
extension Int: Addable {
    func add(other: Int) -> Int {
        return self + other
    }
}
```

### 4) Usage

Now you can use your function with `Int`.

```
commonAdd(1, paramB: 2) // 3
```

### More

You should repeat the step 3 to make `Addable` every Type you want to use in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Conform **AdditiveArithmetic** Protocol for adding genric data type.

```
func commonAdd<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(paramA:T,paramB:T) ->T{
    return item1 + item2
  }
```

If you need to support Strings, make it conform to **AdditiveArithmetic** but you will need to implement subtraction as well:

```
extension String: AdditiveArithmetic {
    public static func -= (lhs: inout String, rhs: String) {
            var set = Set(rhs)
        lhs.removeAll{ !set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
    public static func - (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String {
        var set = Set(rhs)
        return lhs.filter{set.insert($0).inserted}
    }
    public static var zero: String { "" }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Generic function to add (Int, Double, String)

```
func add<T: Any >(itemA: T, itemB: T) -> T {

    if itemA is Int && itemB is Int {
        debugPrint("Int")
        let intNum1 = itemA as! Int
        let intNum2 = itemB as! Int
        return intNum1 + intNum2 as! T
        
    } else if itemA is Double && itemB is Double {
        debugPrint("Double")
        let doubleNum1 = itemA as! Double
        let doubleNum2 = itemB as! Double
        return doubleNum1 + doubleNum2 as! T
    } else {
        debugPrint("String")
        let string1 = itemA as! String
        let string2 = itemB as! String
        return string1 + string2 as! T
        
    }
    
}
```